# Angle between two vectors given magnitudes only

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a physics problem about vectors:

> Two vectors $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ have precisely equal magnitudes. For the magnitude of $\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}$ to be $100$ times larger than the magnitude of $\boldsymbol{A} - \boldsymbol{B}$, what must be the angle between them?

I have tried to draw a diagram and calculate the problem with geometrical methods with two simultaneous equations of the form $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos θ$:$$
|\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}|² = |\boldsymbol{A}|² + |\boldsymbol{B}|² - 2|\boldsymbol{A}||\boldsymbol{B}|\cos θ\\
|\boldsymbol{A} - \boldsymbol{B}|² = |\boldsymbol{A}|² + |\boldsymbol{B}|² - 2|\boldsymbol{A}||\boldsymbol{B}|\cos(π - θ)
$$
Equating these two equations in terms of $θ$ gives$$
\cos θ = -\frac{9999|\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{B}|²}{|4|\boldsymbol{A}|²|}.
$$

This is as far as i could get, any help solving the problem will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry didn't complete the question... been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the fact that $|A| = |B|$

$|A+B| = 100|A-B|\\
|A|^2 + |B|^2 + 2|A||B|\cos \theta = 100^2(|A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2|A||B|\cos \theta)$

let $a = |A| = |B|$

$a^2 + a^2 + 2a^2\cos\theta = 100^2(a^2 + a^2 - 2a^2\cos\theta)$

Isolate $\cos \theta$ and simplify

$2(100^2+ 1)a^2 \cos \theta = 2a^2(100^2-1)\\
\theta = \arccos \frac {100^2 - 1}{100^2 + 1}$

[image]

Comment: The solution is correct thankyou, although I dont understand why | **A + B** | has an angle of π-θ. I got it that between **A** and -**B** the angle = π-θ

Comment: Your solution gives an answer of 1.14... should the angle between the vectors not be almost 180 degrees?

Comment: They are almost parallel.  To add vectors place them head to tail (forming a parallelogram.)  The difference between the two vectors is the opposite diagonal (from head to head)

Comment: The diagram clears it up thanks

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively they need to be almost in the same direction.  The sum will be (almost) twice the length of one vector and the difference will be the (small) sideways component between them.  We can divide by the length and work with unit vectors, then choose our coordinates so that $A=(1,0),B=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.  The angle between them is then $\pi-\theta$
The length of the sum is then $\sqrt{(1+\cos \theta)^2+\sin^2 \theta}=\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta}$.
The length of the difference is $\sqrt{(1-\cos \theta)^2+\sin^2 \theta}=\sqrt{2-2 \cos \theta}$
Let $\cos \theta=c$ to save typing and we want 
$$\frac {\sqrt{2+2c}}{\sqrt{2-2c}}=100\\\frac {2+2c}{2-2c}=10000\\
2+2c=20000-20000c\\c=\frac{19998}{20002}\\ \theta=\arccos \frac {19998}{20002}
\approx 0.0199999$$